# Normal distribution appears too dense when plotted in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, statistics

I am trying to estimate the probability density function of my data. IN my case, the data is a satellite image with a shape 8200 x 8100.
Below, I present you the code of PDF (the function 'is_outlier' is borrowed by a guy that post this code on here ). As we can see, the PDF is in figure 1 too dense. I guess, this is due to the thousands of pixels that the satellite image is composed of. This is very ugly.

My question is, how can I plot a PDF that is not too dense? something like shown in figure 2 for example.

```
lst = 'satellite_img.tif' #import the image
lst_flat = lst.flatten() #create 1D array

#the function below removes the outliers
def is_outlier(points, thres=3.5):

    if len(points.shape) == 1:
        points = points[:,None]
    median = np.median(points, axis=0)
    diff = np.sum((points - median)**2, axis=-1)
    diff = np.sqrt(diff)
    med_abs_deviation = np.median(diff)

    modified_z_score = 0.6745 * diff / med_abs_deviation

    return modified_z_score > thres


lst_flat = np.r_[lst_flat]
lst_flat_filtered = lst_flat[~is_outlier(lst_flat)]
fit = stats.norm.pdf(lst_flat_filtered, np.mean(lst_flat_filtered), np.std(lst_flat_filtered))

plt.plot(lst_flat_filtered, fit)
plt.hist(lst_flat_filtered, bins=30, normed=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

figure 1

[image]
figure 2

Comment: Could you provide the image and make the example reproducible.

Comment: An option would be to only plot certains PDFs by using a slice of the PDF array. Try PDF[:, ::2] with 2 the steps.

Comment: hmm, that's a good though. I will try to slice the PDF. Thanks

Comment: Hi Martin, I do not know if it is feasible to provide the datasets I am using. The reason is that, I am calculating the land surface temperature of a city using THERMAL satellite data(this requires 3 images of different bands like Near Infra red,RED and thermal band) and try to do some statistics on it. Also, the the images are quite big. I will try though

Comment: You are not meant to post your complete data here. Read [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the x values in the PDF plot are not sorted, so the plotted line is going back and forwards between random points, creating the mess you see.

Two options:

1. Don't plot the line, just plot points (not great if you have lots of points, but will confirm if what I said above is right or not):

   ```
   plt.plot(lst_flat_filtered, fit, 'bo')
   ```
2. Sort the `lst_flat_filtered` array before calculating the PDF and plotting it:

   ```
   lst_flat = np.r_[lst_flat]
   lst_flat_filtered = np.sort(lst_flat[~is_outlier(lst_flat)])  # Changed this line
   fit = stats.norm.pdf(lst_flat_filtered, np.mean(lst_flat_filtered), np.std(lst_flat_filtered))

   plt.plot(lst_flat_filtered, fit)
   ```

Here's some minimal examples showing these behaviours:

#### Reproducing your problem:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lst_flat_filtered = np.random.normal(7, 5, 1000)

fit = stats.norm.pdf(lst_flat_filtered, np.mean(lst_flat_filtered), np.std(lst_flat_filtered))

plt.hist(lst_flat_filtered, bins=30, normed=True)

plt.plot(lst_flat_filtered, fit)

plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Plotting points

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lst_flat_filtered = np.random.normal(7, 5, 1000)

fit = stats.norm.pdf(lst_flat_filtered, np.mean(lst_flat_filtered), np.std(lst_flat_filtered))

plt.hist(lst_flat_filtered, bins=30, normed=True)

plt.plot(lst_flat_filtered, fit, 'bo')

plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Sorting the data

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lst_flat_filtered = np.sort(np.random.normal(7, 5, 1000))

fit = stats.norm.pdf(lst_flat_filtered, np.mean(lst_flat_filtered), np.std(lst_flat_filtered))

plt.hist(lst_flat_filtered, bins=30, normed=True)

plt.plot(lst_flat_filtered, fit)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: HI, Tom. That was a great answer. Thanks for sending time to reproduce my problem and find a solution for this. I appreciate it. Many thanks